# C# OpenXML: Only getting first hyperlink in file in all files except for the last one

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I've been assigned with writing an application that can go into a directory, find files of a certain type, get any hyperlinks in the file and record them. So far, it's been going smooth. However, for some reason I I'm having an issue with only getting one of the two links in the file. Both links are to the same url. It just seems to ignore the second one of the first two files, but the third one is just fine.

```
        string pathtofolder = "C:\\Users\\Icmolreulf\\source\\repos\\FileSearch\\FileSearch\\powershelltesting";

        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(pathtofolder, "*.docx");
        Console.WriteLine(files.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            WordprocessingDocument word = WordprocessingDocument.Open(files[i], true);
            IEnumerable<HyperlinkRelationship>  link = from x in word.MainDocumentPart.HyperlinkRelationships where (x.RelationshipType == "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink") select x;
            foreach (HyperlinkRelationship l in link)
            {
                if (isValidURL(l.Uri.ToString()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(l.Uri.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    static bool isValidURL(string uriName)
    {
        Uri uriResult;
        bool result = Uri.TryCreate(uriName, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult)
            && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);

        return result;
    }
```

I'm at a loss for what the issue could be. The url I expect to find is the same one for all the files: http://burymewithmymoney.com/. I have ensured it is in all of them. I have also tried adding another .docx file to the directory, and it works, but it also ignores that file too. I'd really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: please provide the url you expect to find and please provide the code of your `isValidUrl()` method, otherwise it's just guessing ;)

Comment: Sorry about that. I figured it wouldn't be needed.

Comment: well the uri is okay and should return true. i recommend to debug step by step to see, where the program really breaks out the loop. One thing to check: does your file enumeration really works (all files found), does the HyperlinkRelationship array has the correct size? if not, the URI is embedded in another way which is not covered by your linq query.

Comment: Okay, so it turns out it's only getting the first of the contents in all the files EXCEPT for the last one. I have two links to http://burymewithmymoney.com/ in each of the files and I have three files. I end up with 4 links to http://burymewithmymoney.com, so do the math and you'll see why I thought I was getting the results from only two of them and missing the last one.

Comment: Hi @Icmolreulf, nice that you could figure out the math :). Did you solve the initial problem? please mark the question as resolve by adding the answer and marking in as resolve.

Comment: Yes, I have solved the issue. Turns out, the issue was with the .docx fils and not the code. I guess it just didn't recognize one of the links for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the files I was reading from. Code works fine. Sorry for taking up your time. Have a nice rest of your day.